# If downloading for a song is disabled, can a 3rd party application that has been authenticated still use the download URL to grab the track?

Tags: soundcloud

I'm trying to create an application using Ruby on Rails that allows a user to download all of the songs that they have uploaded.  At this point I've authenticated the user using OmniAuth, and I've managed to pull some data using Soundcloud's Ruby [interface](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-ruby) with their API.

According to the [API](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks), every track has an associated title, artwork_url, and download_url (I have already used the API to get this information).  I'd like to display each song showing its title and artwork (if any exists), and then if they choose to download that track, they'll be able to click a button and download that track from the download_url.

So here's what I've realized: for most tracks (or sounds, as they are called in Soundcloud), downloading is disabled by default when you upload it.  The thing is, there is also an option that says "Apps Enabled/Disabled."  What I'm wondering is if downloading for a song is disabled, can a 3rd party application that has been authenticated still use the download URL to grab the track?  I'd like to know if users will need to individually go through all their tracks and enable downloading in order for this to work.

If you need any more detail, please say so.  Apologies if this is an obvious question.

Thanks,

Nat

Comment: Oh, also, I'm not entirely sure how to download the song using the download_url, which would look something like this: http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/13158665/download.

Any advice would be very much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: A little more research:

In [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/soundcloudapi/download_url/soundcloudapi/qhzhXGe4Ksg/0C8cvhX_4L4J) forum post, a VP at Soundcloud says that if you are authorized you should always have access to your tracks.  So it makes me thing it might be possible.

At the bottom of [this](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-ruby/issues/12) page, it looks like there's a solution for downloading a song.  I just tried it out and it didn't seem to work; anyone have any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I'm wondering is if downloading for a song is disabled, can a 3rd
>   party application that has been authenticated still use the download
>   URL to grab the track?

Yes, it can. However, note that in order for API to actually serve the file, there has to be an HTTP Authorisation header and client_id GET parameter.

This means that simply spitting out the links like

```
<a href="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/{id}/download">Download {title}</a>
```

will not help. As for `client_id`, you could simply append it to the `href`, but since browser doesn't know about the fact that your app has been authorised and can't send HTTP headers with simple requests, API won't let the user download tracks that are not publicly downloadable.

Because of that, you'll need to build a proxy in ruby and set `href`s to your local endpoints and handle the connection to the SoundCloud API on the ruby side, so you can pass HTTP header with OAuth token.

Comment: So if your app needs an authorization header to do this, how do you get one? I'm trying to make a very basic follow-gate a la toneden.io and found this answer when trying to test downloading a download-disabled track. Is this something where you'd need to ask Soundcloud team personally and tell them you're going to make an follow-gate app, and then they give you the http header? If not, how do you get the http header?

Answer (score 1):

Making an HTTP request (Get) to the API invoking the '/convert' route will return your track ID.

Then you can make a POST request to the api '/stream' passing the track id and ?client_id=YOURCLIENTID

From the response you can get the stream url that can be used to stream and download every track in Soundcloud. The latter option isn't really legal so take all of this as an example.

Edit: This can be done with pure JS/jQuery, no need to run servers